# Display Unicode character in Android webview

Tags: java, android, fonts

I did an android application which displays malayalam ascii encoded fonts in webview.
Now I have to display unicode character set (like &#3384 ; &#3394 ; &#3370 ; &#3405 ; &#3370 ;) but it didn't displaying properly on webview. The text is getting unreadable and meaningless.

1. In Older impl I am having the text like this **Y¢j¤lcÉd¤j«: Jt´Tl¡l¤
   a¢c·**
2. In current impl its like **&#3384 ; &#3394 ; &#3370 ; &#3405 ; &#3370 ;**

So I would like to know is it possible to convert Unicode (ie, from 2) format to the ASCII (ie, to 1) in android ?

The font used is thoolika.ttf.

Thanks in Advance
@nish

Comment: Did you try with `utf-8`

Comment: I would like to know How to convert from the 2nd encoding to the 1st one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:
http://software.clapper.org/javautil/api/org/clapper/util/html/HTMLUtil.html

Comment: Thank you.  But the problem is WebView not displays some complex/combined letters from malayalam properly..

Comment: That package converts unicode characters to html entities which are to displayed in webview. There are a few characters it missed though. I did it well with Vietnamese.